# Accessing Public IP routes to another IP?

Tags: ip, hosting, webclient

I have web client (webApp) that has load balancer in its network (two web WebApp Sever with two different public IPs).
So my problem is, when I'm accessing the primary WebApp it routes to its back up webApp which is the second IP.
for example.

When I access the web Client in Internet Explorer  using this url

> `http://000.000.00.18/AppNet/Login.aspx`

(public IP from VM)
it routed to this url

> `http://000.000.00.19/AppNet/Login.aspx`

.. I dont know why how this one happened., can somebody please help me with this one? Thank you.

Note: Above IPs are just examples.

Comment: Maybe it's just the Login page on .18 that redirects you to the .19 host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved.
The problem was, there was a  mistake in mapping the IP.
The problem is in network admins. grrrrr.